# I am trying subtract in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

This the part of my code messing up.

```
@echo off
set /p year=

:start   
echo Waiting For The Year To Equal %year%
set /a left=%year%-%date:~6,4%
echo %left% Years Left
timeout /nobreak /t 1 >nul
if %date:~6,4%==%year% goto :01
goto :start
```

I can't get "set /a left=%year%-%date:~6,4%" to give a value to "%left%"
This is what I get:

```
Waiting For The Year To Equal 2018
Missing operand.
 Years Left
```

[Click here for above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ7aa.jpg)

Please Help Me!!!!

Comment: It works as expected here ...

Answer (score 0):

```
:start
cls
echo Waiting For The Year To Equal %year%
set dateyear=%date:~10,4%
set /a left=%year%-%dateyear%
echo %left% Years Left
timeout /nobreak /t 1 >nul
if %date:~6,4%==%year% goto :01
goto :start
```

Nevermind but I was able to fix it after I played around with it for a while